# Unable to redirect html

Tags: html, onsubmit

This is my code, and I want to redirect to another site when clicking Submit, and I can't find where is the error. It's a simple code and I know it's a little "ugly" to see, but I'm only testing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <link href="paginaweb.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect(){
      window.location.href("https://www.outlook.com");
      return(false);
    }
    </script>
 </head>
 
  <body class="container">
   <div class="image"> </div>​
    <div>
     <style>
      input[type=text] {
          width: 100%;
          padding: 12px 20px;
          margin: 8px 0;
          box-sizing: border-box;
      }
     </style>
     <label for="email">
     <p class="fuente">Introduce tu email para conectarte a Internet.</p></label>
     <form onsubmit="redirect()">
      <input type="email" placeholder="Your email...">
     <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
     </form>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just set the `form`'s `action` parameter to the URL?

Comment: You need to submit value to other url or just redirect?

Comment: `window.location.replace("https://www.outlook.com");` how about this?

Comment: how about this url:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage-in-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with the following code:

```
<form method="post" action="newurl.com">
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email...">
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Just set the form action and the form data will be sent to the new url.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of **window.location.href**
`window.location.href = "http://example.com";`
Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Answer (score 0):

Answering to myself:

To avoid error 405, change

```
<form method="post" action="newurl.com">
```

for

```
<form method="get" action="newurl.com">
```